# How do I render everything in software using XNA/C#?

Tags: xna, c#

I'm trying to find how to render everything with software in XNA, but I can't find what option I need to set.

I'd like to know which method/properties I have to call/set to make my app run in software mode as opposed to hardware accelerated mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you can use the reference device in XNA 4.0 using this code:

```
GraphicsAdapter.UseReferenceDevice = true
```

Not sure if this works but that is [what the MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsadapter.usereferencedevice%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29).

Comment: There's more on how to use this here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751820/how-can-i-run-xna-in-virtualbox-on-a-mac

Answer (score 0):

Except for maybe debugging shaders why would you want to use software rendering?

You can use the Reference Device but it is extremely slow. I don't normally work in XNA but a quick google found me this: [How to: Use the Reference Device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203927%28v=xnagamestudio.10%29.aspx)

Comment: that code does not compile. GraphicsDeviceInformation does not have CreationOptions, DeviceType & PresentationParameters properties

Comment: btw, I want it to check if some problems are caused by my graphic card or my program.

Comment: @ProgrammerAtWork ah ok, sorry it looks like the link was to XNA 1.0 but SomeWritesReserved found the correct one.

Comment: "I want it to check if some problems are caused by my graphic card or my program" - you should have probably added this to your question otherwise you had a high risk of getting many more similar answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is this [Windows Advanced Rasterization Platform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Advanced_Rasterization_Platform) on the most recent Windows platforms which i think it's what you are looking for or there are commercial solutions like [Pixomatic](http://www.radgametools.com/pixomain.htm).